std::generate - access previous element in vector
I am using std::generate() to construct a struct and push it into a std::vector. In order to construct the struct, I need to refer to the previous struct in the sequence. Is there any way to do this in C++20? I would rather not use a 3rd party library, like boost.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct CashFlow {

    double begin_balance;
    double payment;
    double interest;
    double prin_repayment;
    double end_balance;
    size_t month;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const CashFlow& cf);
};

std::vector<CashFlow> cashflows(n);   

//this is i = 0 struct
CashFlow c;
c.month = 0;
c.begin_balance = initial_prin;
c.end_balance = initial_prin;

cashflows.push_back(c);

std::generate(begin(cashflows) + 1, end(cashflows), [&, i = 1]() 
mutable {
    CashFlow c;
    c.month = i;
    //here I need end_balance member of the previous struct in the vector
    c.begin_balance = std::prev(cashflows.end()).end_balance; // this does not work
    c.payment = payment;
    c.end_balance = initial_prin * ((100 - pow(1 + 0.08, i)) / (100 - 1));
    c.interest = 0.08 * c.begin_balance;
    c.prin_repayment = 80 - c.interest;
    return c;
});


std::prev(cashflows.end()) would be the same as cashflows.back() wouldn't it? Still doesn't seem what you want. You could use an index couldn't you?

Is "previous" even a valid concept in this context?

@RetiredNinja By index, do you mean "c.begin_balance = cashflows[i-1].end_balance" ? Or you suggest I maintain a index variable inside the generate lambda ?

Is cashflows.push_back(c); intentional? It adds the item to the end of the vector and it seems like you want it to be the first item. https://godbolt.org/z/r4cYxzr5K

@RetiredNinja It's a mistake, I need it to be the first item, so that generate loop can make use of it.

@RetiredNinja The godbolt link works perfectly. Thank you!

Your std::generate() lambda can simply store the previous generated value that you want to pass along to the next iteration, just like you are doing with i, eg:
std::vector<CashFlow> cashflows(n);   

//this is i = 0 struct
CashFlow& initial_c = cashflows.front();
initial_c.month = 0;
initial_c.begin_balance = initial_prin;
initial_c.end_balance = initial_prin;

std::generate(begin(cashflows) + 1, end(cashflows),
    [&, i = 1, previous_end_balance = initial_prin]() mutable {
        CashFlow c;
        c.month = i;
        c.begin_balance = previous_end_balance;
        c.payment = payment;
        c.end_balance = initial_prin * ((100 - pow(1 + 0.08, i)) / (100 - 1));
        c.interest = 0.08 * c.begin_balance;
        c.prin_repayment = 80 - c.interest;
        previous_end_balance = c.end_balance;
        ++i;
        return c;
    }
);


This is a great suggestion, I didn't know this. Thank you!
